# Why did only alternative Spider-People came from the Super-Collider?

Tags: marvel, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

Kingpin built the collider to bring members of his family back to life. Instead, alternative Spider-People have been sucked out of their respective dimensions.

How come only Spider-People seem to be affected by the collider, among all people and super-heroes populating the Marvel universe?

Comment: *Spider-Verse* seems to be a setting where Spider-Man and related characters are the only superbeings, which would at least explain why no other heroes came through.

Comment: I thought it was because either Spider-Man or a spider was in the beam during a test, but I may have imagined that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As suggested by OrangeDog in the comments the device focuses on alternative versions of Spiderman because he gets his head shoved into the Beam.

Summary cribbed from [here](https://www.thisisbarry.com/film/into-the-spider-verse-film-comic-characters-comparison/).

> The portal opens and the Green Goblin, who’s fighting Spider-Man, shoves Spidey’s head through the portal causing an explosion. Spider-Man is severely wounded, and the Green Goblin dies.

As seen in this, very low quality clip.